# CRC-3 example code with initial seed, computation with lookup table

Tags: crc

I am working with the MCU which needs to compute the 3-bits width CRC(polynom 0xB, init seed 0x5) from 13-bit message. I'm in dark because I don't know how. The most CRC computes on the web is CRC8/16/32etc, but CRC3 is missing.

I have find the website: http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

where I can generate(I hope that the right) the lookup table, but I don't understand if it is OK. Because the CRC-3 must be a 3bits width but the values in the lookup table have 8-bits width. Can I use this table for calculating the CRC3? If yes, how?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of this CRC? You have not provided enough information on the definition of the CRC, in particular in what order the bits from the message are fed to the CRC.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem worth it to have an 8-bit lookup table for the CRC calculation, since it is being computed on only 13-bits. You would need to do the last five bits one-by-one anyway.

Just do the calculation a bit at a time, or have a 13-bit lookup table that avoids the need for the calculation entirely. It would be only 8192 3-bit entries, which could be packed into 4K bytes.

Your description does not specify the order in which the bits from the message are fed to the CRC. Most significant first or least significant? Also, is there a final exclusive-or of the CRC?

Here is some simple code in C that takes the 13-bit message as the least-siginificant 13-bits in an unsigned integer (the rest have to be zero), and returns the CRC, assuming it processes from the least significant bit first, and that there is no final exclusive-or:

```c
unsigned crc3(unsigned msg) {
    msg ^= 5;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        msg = msg & 1 ? (msg >> 1) ^ 6 : msg >> 1;
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: The bits order, LSB or MSB, is not mentioned in the descritption of computation. The citation from datasheet: "The CRC-3 is calculated over the Reg bits1[4:0], Reg bits2[7:6], Reg bits3[5:3] and Reg bits4[2:0]. The generator polynom is x3 + x + 1 and the seed is 0x5." Thats enough...I should cntact the vendor for more detals.

Comment: You can't provide a link?